Why is EXEC MASTER..xp_fixeddrives not 100% accurate?
I want to programmatically oversee a lot of different SQL Servers and know their free space in order to do something if it drops below a threshold.
However MASTER..xp_fixeddrives does not return the exact free space of the different drives even though most posts I read do not mention anything about divergence.
The deviation from the actual free space also ranges. It seems that the larger the disk space, the bigger the deviation.
When I run the command I get the following results:
C | 27532 MB
D | 364740 MB
But the actual free space when connecting to the server through RDP and checking the drives is:
C | 26.8 GB
D | 356 GB
Does anyone know why it is not accurate or what exactly it takes into consideration?

You have to do MB / 1024.0 to get the GB value, they look pretty accurate to me there

It always bugs me that Microsoft uses "MB" to mean Mebibytes, not Megabytes...

Damn dude, I feel so dumb for asking this now. Thanks a lot @siggemannen.

xp_fixeddrives is undocumented, so all bets are off. Why do you need to access the file system from T-SQL anyway, why not use Powershell etc?

@Charlieface I read suggestions to do it with an automated Job that has a threshold. Did not find a better automated alternative. Feel free to suggest one.

It's literally one line of Powershell Get-Volume | ft DriveLetter,Size,SizeRemaining

If you need a more accurate results up to a byte, you can use a more modern DMV.
SQL
SELECT *
    ,free_space_in_bytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0) 'Free Space (GB)'
FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_fixed_drives;

Output



fixed_drive_path
drive_type
drive_type_desc
free_space_in_bytes
Free Space (GB)




C:\
3
DRIVE_FIXED
313952243712
292.3908119201660156


E:\
3
DRIVE_FIXED
797594169344
742.8174552917480468



